# How do I set the office 2007 style with Infragistics?

Tags: c#, infragistics, styling

I have been looking to set the office 2007 form style using infragistics, but just cant find the code lines i need (which I suspect are very few!)

Does anyone have the code I need or a link to a tutorial? Looking on the infragistics site the samples seem few (or I just cant find them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked it out:

1. Add a UltraToolbarsManager
2. Turn the Ribbon Subobject Visible Property to TRUE

Your app switches entire form style to Office 2007.